# The set $\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}|x_{1}=0\right\}\cup\left\{x \in\mathbb{R}^{3}| x_{2}=0\right\}$ is linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Another task from a test-exam:

> True or false? The set $\left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3} | x_{1}=0\right\}
> \cup \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}| x_{2}=0\right\}$ is a linear
>   subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

I would say this statement is false because we have $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ but only one element in both sets, I think it had to be a triple, something like $(0,1,2)$ to be true.

But as you can see I'm not sure at all and I would be very happy for some explanatory answers :)

Because we didn't get the solutions sadly.

Comment: In general, the union of finitely many vector subspaces $V_1,\cdots, V_n$ is a vector subspace if and only if there is some $i$ such that for all $k$ it holds $V_i\supseteq V_k$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Over an infinite field.

Comment: @egreg Whoops. True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $(0,1,1)$ belongs to the first set, $(1,0,0)$ belongs to the second set; what about the sum?

Comment: I don't understand why you asking me this :s The sum should be $(1,1,1)$, right? And this would be in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. But how can you say that $(0,1,1)$ belongs to first set, $(1,0,0)$ belongs to second? Because task says $x_{1}=0$ and other set $x_{2}=0$ Or your example doesn't belong to my task, it's another one explaining this one?  I'm confused :P

Comment: @cnmesr Does the sum belong to the union of the two sets?

Comment: Hmm I think the union of the two sets would be $\left\{(0,1,1),(1,0,0)\right\}$ and the sum would be $(1,1,1)$ and this is not in the union.

Comment: @cnmesr Exactly; therefore…

Comment: Therefor the statement is false..? But why did you ask for the sum?

Comment: @cnmesr If the *union* is a subspace, it would be closed under *sum* of its elements.

Comment: Alright then everything understood, thank you very much again :)